# “column ”Id“ of relation ”vip_clients“ does not exist” exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql

**I am trying to add to the data base VipClient.**

Here is a chart database:
[image]

Model:

```
public class VipClient
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class VipClientMap : IMappingEntity<VipClient>
{
    public void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<VipClient> builder)
    {
        builder.ForNpgsqlToTable("vip_clients", "clients");
        builder.HasKey(entity => entity.Id);

        builder
            .HasOne(entity => entity.Client)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("vip_client_id");

        builder
            .Property(entity => entity.Comment)
            .HasColumnName("vip_client_comment")
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(entity => entity.CreationTime)
            .HasColumnName("creation_time")
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

When I add new VipClient to DB - it “column ”Id“ of relation ”vip_clients“ does not exist” exception

I think that problem is in mapping

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: @Rob “column ”Id“ of relation ”vip_clients“ does not exist” exception

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with capitalization. How is the `Id` column shown on the database (with psql or pgAdmin)? To be certain what is going on, log the SQL statement on the database server: set the parameters `log_min_error_statement = error` and `log_min_messages = error` and the statement will be logged.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe In DB this column is 'vip_client_id'